# How to verify that a detached command is running in a container

Tags: docker, jobs

I have a running docker container and I execute a new detached command using

```sh
docker exec -d myContainer sh -c "/path/to/myExecutable"
```

I would assume that "-d Detached mode: run command in the background" ([Docker exec documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/edge/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)) would be similar to running a command like so:

```sh
/path/to/myExecutable &
```

But if it was, then I should see the pid when I run `jobs` and I do not.
Is the script still running?  Where would it's output be?

Note: I'm running the [node:10.15.3](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) image

Comment: I guess detach mode is not similar to ```/path/to/myExecutable &```. 
You would be able to see the pid using ```pa -A```
Also if your Executable is writing to ```stdout``` then you can see the output by ```docker logs myContainer```

Comment: What’s your larger-scale use case?  Trying to have multiple long-running processes in a single container isn’t usually encouraged.

Comment: @DavidMaze just to run a one-off script and make sure it continues to run until it's finished even if I close my terminal.

Comment: @Sumit, my image doesn't contain the `pa` command, and the output doesn't show up in `docker logs` even though the script will print to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> --detach , -d     Detached mode: run command in the background

This not means the command you specify in `docker run xxx command` will be run in background, it just means the `docker run` this command will be run in background, or say will return to bash at once after it calles, it's a async call.

E.g. We new a container, and currently we see no `yes command` run(PS: linux `yes` command will run never exit):

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker run -idt --name try alpine
301afb11661ca8aee676f01abf55172f44e469ee977df05682ad1b49a4d218b0
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker exec try ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh
    6 root      0:00 ps aux
```

**1. exec with -d**

You can see next, `docker exec -d try yes` return to `bash($)` at once after command execute, and also if check again in container with `ps aux`, we can see `yes process` is just there:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker exec -d try yes
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker exec try ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh
   11 root      0:05 yes
   16 root      0:00 ps aux
```

**2. exec without -d**

You can see next, `docker exec try yes` will not return to `bash($)`, just print `y` endlessly. And if you `Ctrl+C` to return to bash, you could now see there are 2 yes command there(first one is the yes in step1, second one is just the yes in step2)

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker exec try yes
y
y
y
y
y
y
^C
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker exec try ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh
   11 root      5:45 yes
   21 root      0:03 yes
   27 root      0:00 ps aux
```

This means with `-d` & without `-d`, it just effect on the `docker run`, not effect the process in the container.

Finally, your question:

> just to run a one-off script and make sure it continues to run until it's finished even if I close my terminal.

You can just use `docker exec -d xxx` to execute it, it won't leave as you can confirm it with `docker exec xxx ps aux`.

Comment: Why does PID 21 stick around even after you exit with Ctrl+C?

Comment: Ctrl+C is sent to `docker exec` not to `yes`, so `yes` will always run in container.

Comment: Doesn't that then mean that the command is running in the background regardless?  I thought that sending Ctrl+C to `docker exec -it` would abort the command that it was running?

Comment: `Ctrl+C` send signal to `docker exec`, not to the process in container. In fact `exec` just give a ability to outside to access the namespace of PID1 of docker container, the `yes` is the subprocess of `PID1`, has no relationship with `docker exec`, so `ctrl+c` will just affect on `docker exec`, has no effect on `yes process`.

Comment: Then what is the difference between using the `-d` and not?  Just that my terminal won't leave a connection open to the container as it does with `-it`?

Comment: Same with the difference of `docker run -d` & `docker run -it`, why `docker run` needs it, then also the reason why `docker exec` need it... I think surely you are able to verify it with your own small experiment...

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to discuss with me.  Cheers!